# Setting/Configuring the output file after running scrapy spider

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm able to run a scrapy spider from a script. But I want to store the output in a specific file(say output.json) in json format. I did a lot of research & also tried to override FEED_URI & FEED_FORMAT from settings. I also tried to use JsonItemExporter function but all in vain. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you running your spider? please share your code

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use scrapy crawl yourspider -o output.json -t json

where -o output filename and -t output format.

Answer (score 0):

Use either of the following commands

```
scrapy crawl yourspidername --set FEED_URI=output.json --set FEED_FORMAT=json

scrapy crawl yourspidername -o output.json -t json
```

Comment: any idea how to set it in setting (file name + location)?